# Correct symbolic link to load ssl module on compiled apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, debian-stretch

I'm trying to replicate a server configuration for an old system, which uses old apache and php versions, specifically apache 2.2.4, in order to compile this version of apache, I had to install openssl 0.9.7 (to avoid an error while compiling apache), when I try to ./apachectl start I get this error:

httpd: Syntax error on line 54 of /usr/local/apache/php/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache/php/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: libssl.so.0.9.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Line 54

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

mod_ssl.so directory:

```
/usr/local/apache/php/modules
```

libssl.so.0.9.7 directory:

```
/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

I tried:

```
ln -s /usr/local/apache/php/modules/mod_ssl.so /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7
```

and

```
ln -s /usr/local/apache/php/modules /usr/local/ssl/lib
```

but still getting the same error above.

This is my `ldd /usr/local/apache/php/modules/mod_ssl.so output`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcfe550000)
    libssl.so.0.9.7 => not found
    libcrypto.so.0.9.7 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe22a31d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe229f7e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe22a765000)
```

Directory to openssl .so files:

```
    root@debian:/usr/local/ssl/lib# ls
libcrypto.a   libcrypto.so.0      libssl.a   libssl.so.0      modules
libcrypto.so  libcrypto.so.0.9.7  libssl.so  libssl.so.0.9.7  pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

For most applications default directory for this type of files is `/usr/lib/`, try moving all libraries into it or create a symlink like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7 /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7
sudo ln -s /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
```

If only this doesn't work:

```
sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf
```

change the path

```
# libc default configuration

# /usr/local/lib

/usr/lib
```

and

```
sudo ldconfig
```